# Raspberry Pi stuck in login / Shutdown loop - console won't open (Raspbian)

Tags: raspberry-pi, console, raspbian

I've gone to numerous places for help on this issue, and decided to come here next.

The other day, I created some usr called "noob" on my RPi, big whoop. Upon a reboot, I was presented with this screen that [tells me to either login or shutdown the pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCr7K.png). Alright, I enter the normal password "raspberry" for the account "pi". The screen goes black for a second, and resets back to the same login screen as above. Most solutions I've seen require access to a console; usually using the ctrl+alt+F1 Hotkey, but that hotkey doesn't work for me. In fact, *no hotkeys I've found open a TTY or a console*. How do you suggest I open a console, or even gain access back to the desktop?

Thanks a million!